# What does pg_basebackup do?

Tags: postgresql, data-recovery, disaster-recovery

I perform some steps to do PITR by referring https://opensourcedbms.com/dbms/how-to-do-point-in-time-recovery-with-postgresql-9-2-pitr-3/ site.

I would like to know what pg_basebackup actually does? I want to know, what Postgres does? Some times I notice `000000010000000000000006.000000D0.backup` files are created in pg_xlog directory. Its content is as:

```
START WAL LOCATION: 0/60000D0 (file 000000010000000000000006)
STOP WAL LOCATION: 0/60001D8 (file 000000010000000000000006)
CHECKPOINT LOCATION: 0/6000108
BACKUP METHOD: pg_start_backup
BACKUP FROM: master
START TIME: 2016-10-01 15:10:52 IST
LABEL: myBaseBackupByPgStartBackup
STOP TIME: 2016-10-01 15:15:42 IST
```

I want to know its functionality and what it does internally whenever we perform `pg_basebackup`?

Comment: As regards the .backup file that gets created during the pg_basebackup. the .backup gets created in your specified wal archive folder after a pg_basebackup when archiving is active. I noticed that if I did not remove this file from the archived wal set when attempting a cluster restore, then it would limit the wal archive files applied on restart to  those detailed in the file.

Comment: So when attempting to restore a pg_basebackup from 3 days ago and using wal archives from then till now, if I left that .backup file in the archived wal folder, only one or two archived wals from close to the time of the pg_basebackup operation were copied over and applied. If I removed it and restarted, all 3 days wal archives were applied

Answer (score 3):

---

**TL;DR;**

---

**PostgreSQL** is a database that holds information really well in a standard way.

**pg_basebackup** takes a backup of the data (data clusters) in a binary format so you can restore your database later if you need to. This is in contrast with pg_dump which would backup a single database, pg_basebackup copies the entire PostgreSQL data cluster (all the databases/tables/fields/rows/ect).

---

**Full Notation**

---

Well, Postgres is "... an object-relational database management system (ORDBMS) with an emphasis on extensibility and standards-compliance. As a database server, its primary function is to store data securely, and to allow for retrieval at the request of other software applications. It can handle workloads ranging from small single-machine applications to large Internet-facing applications with many concurrent users." -

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL

And the backup "**pg_basebackup is used to take base backups of a running PostgreSQL database cluster.** These are taken without affecting other clients to the database, and can be used both for point-in-time recovery (see Section 24.3) and as the starting point for a log shipping or streaming replication standby servers (see Section 25.2).

**pg_basebackup makes a binary copy of the database cluster files**, while making sure the system is put in and out of backup mode automatically. Backups are always taken of the entire database cluster; it is not possible to back up individual databases or database objects. For individual database backups, a tool such as pg_dump must be used.

**Note that there are some limitations in an online backup from the standby:**

- The backup history file is not created in the database cluster backed
  up.
- There is no guarantee that all WAL files required for the backup are
  archived at the end of backup. If you are planning to use the backup
  for an archive recovery and want to ensure that all required files
  are available at that moment, you need to include them into the
  backup by using -x option.
- If the standby is promoted to the master during online backup, the
  backup fails.
- All WAL records required for the backup must contain sufficient
  full-page writes, which requires you to enable full_page_writes on
  the master and not to use a tool like pg_compresslog as
  archive_command to remove full-page writes from WAL files.
  " - Taken directly from the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pgbasebackup.html)